# A simpler way to get the current time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, time

I need to store the current time (format `'hi'`) as char(4) in a table (is created and used by another program, I can't change it) and now wondered what is a suitable way to retrieve it via SQL. I know MySQL is not that standard-orientated, but I thought it could be something similiar to `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), 'Hi').` 
The code below which I found works, but feels little  intricately.

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(hour, GETDATE()) AS nvarchar)+CAST(DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) AS nvarchar);
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following gives the same result:

```
SELECT LEFT(STUFF(CONVERT(NCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 8), 3, 1,''), 4)
```

It seems to have approximately the same performance as the method from question. I tested it like this:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0,
        @dto1 DATETIME2,
        @dto2 DATETIME2

SET @dto1 = SYSDATETIME()
WHILE @i < 100000
BEGIN
    PRINT LEFT(STUFF(CONVERT(NCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 8), 3, 1,''), 4)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END 
SET @dto2 = SYSDATETIME()

SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @dto1, @dto2)
```

Comment: The method in the question can return the wrong results too if run at exactly midnight. It has two references to `GETDATE()`. It is possible that it could end up reporting `23:00` instead of either `23:59` OR `00:00`

Comment: Indeed, it's possible to imagine such case, unless the SQL Server engine wouldn't specifically give the same value to both GETDATE() references because they're in the same statement.

Comment: @Ivan__83 so it couldn't happen to retrieve wrong values as long as I stay on the same query? I mean, in this case it doesn't matter because the employees won't work around midnight, just for my general knowledge.

Comment: @32bitfloat If this error is possible it wouldn't be limited only to midnight, it could occur on every boundary between two hours. DATETIME data type supports precision up to every third millisecond, so the last time value in any hour ends with 7, for instance 14:59:59.997, if that would be the value obtained by first call to GETDATE(), then the next time value obtained from the second call to GETDATE() could possibly be 15:00:00.000, which would result in value "1400".

Answer (score 3):

Sql Server 2008 has a `time` datatype:

```
select replace(left(cast(getdate() as time), 5), ':', '')
```